# Нечестный тест на внимательность

Tags: поддержка, аудит

Есть проверочный пользовательский аудит:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/83960
Не вижу причин, по которым ответ нужно рекомендовать к удалению. Он выглядит нормально с точки зрения и длины, качества и оформления, именно поэтому я и нажимаю "Выглядит нормально".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Рискну предположить, что данный ответ попал в проверку на внимательность из-за того, что на нем нажали тревогу и по тревоге он был удален модератором.
То есть налицо некачественный подбор вопросов для проверки аудиторов в алгоритме движка.
Не должны туда попадать затревоженные ответы "Несет вред", потому что они могут выглядеть качественными ответами, а аудитор не обязан быть специалистом по вопросу, если он ведет проверку "Сообщения низкого качества".

---

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/62178  (с) Кнопкатык
Точно такой же случай- сообщение изменено до вменяемого состояния, но находится в проверке аудиторов

Comment: Ответ выглядит нормально, вот только вопрос был про MySQL, а ответ - про SQL Server, да еще и со спамерской ссылкой внутри.

Comment: @PashaPash: Тем не менее, ответ и правда _выглядит нормально_. Поэтому я бы предложил убрать его из списка «проверочных» ответов.

Comment: [Аналогичный случай](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/62178).

Comment: Снял отметки "спам" с ответа. Полагаю, теперь эта проблема не повторится.

Answer (score 10):

Это спамерское сообщение. Проблема в том, что модератор [сначала удалил спамерскую ссылку, а только потом сам ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/518572/revisions). В результате в аудите оказалась версия без ссылки.

Кстати, ответ без ссылки вполне соответствует правилам, да и насчёт спамерства я не абсолютно уверен (выглядит как честная ссылка на полезный инструмент), поэтому как неспециалист не могу определить, [модераторский-произвол](/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb) это или нет. :)